# C; If I put a break in a for loop inside a while loop

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop, boolean, break

I am doing this in C, NOT C++. Anyways, if I put a break statement inside a for loop, will it stop the for loop only or both the for and the while loop? For example, here is the part of my code with the while and the for. What I'm doing is letting the user enter a 24 hour time, and I'm checking the minutes in this loop (which is hopefully correct). What I'm concerned about is if the break statement will end the for loop only or if it will end both the for and the while, since I only want the for loop to end.

```
boolean check = false;
while (!check){
    int i;
            for (i = 1; i < 24; i++)
            {
                    int hour = i*100;
                    /* if the time has less hours than the hour counter*/
                    if ((hour - timeOfDay) < 100)
                    {
                    /*declare an illegal time when the number of minutes remaining*/
                    /*is greater than 59*/
                            if ((hour - timeOfDay) > 59)
                            {  
                                    check = false;
                                    break;
                            }
                    }
            }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you need to set the silly flag to "true" somewhere ?

Answer (score 14):

It will only break the inner `for` loop and not the outer `while` loop.
You can actually test this with a minimalistic code sample before you posted the question.I guess it would take same amount of time as much as framing the Q.

Answer (score 5):

From the C standard:(Section 6.8.6.3)

**Constraints**

A break statement shall appear only in or as a switch body or loop body.

**Semantics**

A break statement terminates execution of the smallest enclosing switch or iteration
statement.

Answer (score 1):

If you put it inside `for` loop it will stop/break the `for` loop only.

Comment: True in this case. Not true if the `for` loop is not the innermost loop.

Comment: yeah I was particular with this case only.

Answer (score 0):

As `break` executes, the program stops executing the other statements below it and just come outside the `loop` and start from the statements just after the loop body where `break` is present.
Here in this case it will just come out of the inner `for` loop.
If you want to do some demo just put one statement `(eg printf("outside inner loop");)` after the closing curly brace } of `for` loop.
Then you will see the execution of that statement.